# Spring Repositories and DATA_FORMAT with nativeQuery=false

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I am trying do something super simple but with Spring Repositories somethings is a bit hard. Basically I wanted to **group by** with DATE_FORMAT, example:

```
 @Query("SELECT " +
             "    new users.bridge.models.dto.PerformanceDTO(sum(t.gl), sum(t.gl)) " +
             "FROM " +
             "    Transaction t " +
             "GROUP BY DATA_FORMATE(t.createdDate,'%Y-%m-%d')")
```

But it throws a syntax error. Is there a way to do that with spring repositories? I don't want to use nativeQuery=true flag, otherwise I can not use this syntax

```
new gara.users.bridge.models.dto.PerformanceDTO(sum(t.gl), sum(t.gl))
```

**UPDATE:**

The erros are: 
 [image]

all the java stack is quite big but:

```
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: asc near line 1, column 180 [SELECT     new gara.users.bridge.models.dto.PerformanceDTO(sum(t.gl), sum(t.gl),t.createdDate) FROM     gara.model.db.Transaction t GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(t.createdDate,'%Y-%m-%d') asc]
```

Comment: Can you add full log related syntax error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you specify `nativeQuery=false` (the default) you need to use valid JPQL.
JPQL doesn't know the function `DATE_FORMAT` but you can use [the generic `FUNCTION` function](https://thoughts-on-java.org/database-functions/) which allows you to call arbitrary SQL functions.

So a group by clause like this should work: `GROUP BY FUNCTION('DATA_FORMAT', t.createdDate,'%Y-%m-%d')`

Just be aware that such queries aren't portable between databases.

> but with Spring Repositories somethings is a bit hard.

You can always fall back on [custom method implementations](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.single-repository-behavior) which shouldn't be much harder than implementing your repository yourself in the first place.